# Dynamically add options to select2 with a POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to add options dynamically to a multiselect form using Select2. Backend is Ruby on Rails and I have defined a create method for the "genre" model (it's a movie db) in question that takes input as json and adds to the database.

The code below works, but only somewhat :)
when I want to add a new genre "abc" - first of all, the select2 drop-down shows "no results" (and doesn't give the option to add the genre).
However in the BACKEND - the entry is actually created and available for future manipulations. In addition - there isn't just one genre "abc" added, but actually one "a", another one "ab", and a third one "abc".

So two things I need to fix - and I don't know enough JS to know how... :/ ...

1. how do I ensure that only ONE genre - "abc" is created?
2. how do I make sure that the genre is shown during creation, and selected properly when I update the form?

Code:

```
  $("#genre-select").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    createTag: function (params) {
      let term = $.trim(params.term);
      $.post("/genres.json", { genre: { name: term } });
    },
  });
```